# I can't access Magento backend with the first time installation. Magento 2.0.11

Tags: magento2, database, magento-2.1

I have a Magento 2.0.11 installed into XAMPP.
The installation is okay, but when I finish this and I wan't to go to Admin Page, Magento redirect me to a different url.

http://localhost/magento/admin_9zmscg/admin/index/index/key/70f34c5c85ee5c60ce1b15daed441b33e3b37e15684ee363e8d54207582b76a0/

I have the basic configuration.

Please help, I want to finish this school's work :((

Comment: whats the issue ? according the your link. url is correct ? what the error are you facing ?

Comment: after fresh installation use two command 1) `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` 2) `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: @Bhavik I can use this commands in Windows 10?

Comment: @ManthanDave I can't access Admin Page because I have 404 error when Magento redirect me to this URL

Comment: in windows 10 wht setup u use? xaamp or wamp?

Comment: @Bhavik XAMPP ..

Comment: Xampp control panel -> right side (shell command) click and go to magento root folder path and run command

Comment: r u setup installation by localhost? or 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Bhavik I have a localhost installation

Comment: @Bhavik I have executed the commands but the result hasn't changed, it continues with the error 404 and that url                       EDIT: Now I can't access anything, when I go to localhost/magento I have a error:   "There has been an error processing your request" Excepting printing is disabled by default for security reasons    Error log record number: 1983784585

Comment: if u done setup by http://localhost/etc... then u want to go database nd nedd to change http://lovalhost/admin to http:://127.0.0.1/admin in `core_config_data` table and column `path: web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`

Comment: and try to open with http://127.0.0.1/...  instead of http://localhost...

Comment: @Bhavik I don't have any table core_config_data... I think that I don't have any idea to install Magento :)))